# How do to solve this Fourier series.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the function defined in the interval $(a, b)$
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^x & \text{if $a\leq x< \frac{b}{2} $} \\
-x^4 & \text{if $\frac{b}{2} \leq x < b$}
\end{cases}
$$
given $a<0<b$ and $a^2>b^2$

I am having trouble writing down the integrals i need to solve since it is not clear to me what are the intervals of integration.
I think that $-1< b < 0$  and $a \in (\infty ,-1]$ but i don't know exactly how to get from there. Are the coefficients simply calculated like
$$
\frac{2}{a+b} \int_{a}^{\frac{b}{2}} e^x \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a+b}\right) dx
$$
or am i missing something? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever solving a Fourier Series Problem , Think of it like this:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{A_{0}}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_{n}cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) + 
B_{n}sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) )
\end{equation}

Now in your case: $$L = \frac{b-a}{2}$$

Hence you get:
\begin{equation}
{A}_n = \frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{b-a})dx \\
{B}_n = \frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{b-a})dx
\end{equation}
Just remember your function switches at x > $\frac{b}{2}$,

Thus go $a$ to $\frac{b}{2}$ and then $\frac{b}{2}$ to $b$ in both of your integrals.

Comment: thank you, i see what was wrong with the way i was doing it